# Rasa error disappears after deleting database conversations Why?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I have a strange problem in Rasa. When I deleted some action name or changed some action name. At the same time, I also deleted some slots. Rasa will get the following error:

```
2019-10-12 13:57:58 ERROR    rasa.core.trackers  - Tried to set non existent slot 'mathcalc'. Make sure you added all your slots to your domain file.
2019-10-12 13:57:58 ERROR    rasa.core.trackers  - Tried to set non existent slot 'mathcalc'. Make sure you added all your slots to your domain file.
2019-10-12 13:57:58 ERROR    rasa.core.trackers  - Tried to set non existent slot 'mathcalc'. Make sure you added all your slots to your domain file.
2019-10-12 13:57:58 ERROR    rasa.core.trackers  - Tried to set non existent slot 'mathcalc'. Make sure you added all your slots to your domain file.
2019-10-12 13:57:58 ERROR    rasa.core.trackers  - Tried to set non existent slot 'mathcalc'. Make sure you added all your slots to your domain file.

2019-10-12 13:57:58 WARNING  rasa.core.featurizers  - Feature 'intent_calc_plus' could not be found in feature map.
2019-10-12 13:57:58 WARNING  rasa.core.featurizers  - Feature 'active_form_meeting_form' could not be found in feature map.
2019-10-12 13:57:58 WARNING  rasa.core.featurizers  - Feature 'entity_mathcalc' could not be found in feature map.
2019-10-12 13:57:58 WARNING  rasa.core.featurizers  - Feature 'intent_calc_plus' could not be found in feature map.
2019-10-12 13:57:58 WARNING  rasa.core.featurizers  - Feature 'active_form_meeting_form' could not be found in feature map.
2019-10-12 13:57:58 WARNING  rasa.core.featurizers  - Feature 'entity_mathcalc' could not be found in feature map.
2019-10-12 13:57:58 WARNING  rasa.core.featurizers  - Feature 'intent_calc_plus' could not be found in feature map.

2019-10-13 09:08:21 WARNING  rasa.core.domain  - Failed to use action 'action_calc_plus' in history. Please make sure all actions are listed in the domains action list. If you recently removed an action, don't worry about this warning. It should stop appearing after a while. 
2019-10-13 09:08:21 WARNING  rasa.core.domain  - Failed to use action 'action_calc_minus' in history. Please make sure all actions are listed in the domains action list. If you recently removed an action, don't worry about this warning. It should stop appearing after a while. 
2019-10-13 09:08:21 WARNING  rasa.core.domain  - Failed to use action 'action_calc_divide' in history. Please make sure all actions are listed in the domains action list. If you recently removed an action, don't worry about this warning. It should stop appearing after a while. 
2019-10-13 09:08:21 WARNING  rasa.core.domain  - Failed to use action 'action_calc_multiply' in history. Please make sure all actions are listed in the domains action list. If you recently removed an action, don't worry about this warning. It should stop appearing after a while. 
2019-10-13 09:08:21 WARNING  rasa.core.domain  - Failed to use action 'action_calc_multiply' in history. Please make sure all actions are listed in the domains action list. If you recently removed an action, don't worry about this warning. It should stop appearing after a while.
```

The slot 'mathcalc' and Feature 'intent_calc_plus' and action 'action_calc_plus' that I have deleted. 
The above error disappears only when I delete the conversations table. What is the reason?
I can't delete the conversations table in the production environment.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like I'm a bit late at answering but here it is.

You are getting that error because when the user re-initiates the conversation with the bot, rasa first retrieves the conversation it had before with the user (called a `tracker`). This means that in the previous conversation, it had the slot `mathcalc`. But this time when it tries to populate the slot `mathcalc`, it can't because it doesn't exist this time. This is the reason that you're getting the error.

Here is what a tracker looks like:

```
{
 "sender_id": "2408196042602645",
  "slots": {
    "mathcalc": null,
    ...
  },
 "latest_message": {...},
 "events": [...]
}
```

To solve the problem, you should re-train your bot with the new data and it should be fine.

The reason that this problem disappears when you delete the `conversations` table is because the previous conversation doesn't exist and so it doesn't try to re-create the last conversation.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I retrained the model with new data, but this error did not disappear.Is there any other caching mechanism in it?

Comment: Looks like i didn't make it clear in the answer. You can safely ignore the error. You'll still get the warning from the tracker but after training, the warning from the featurizer should be gone.